# Diferenças entre as versões 3.x e 2.7 do Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Vou começar um projeto na faculdade relacionado a maquinas de busca e quero aproveitar a oportunidade para também aprender Python.

Não sei muito a respeito da linguagem e minha maior dúvida é sobre qual versão, entre a 3.x e a 2.7, tem um melhor suporte para tratamento de strings, como é o suporte a bibliotecas, e quais são os recursos que elas oferecem para desenvolvimento web.

Como decidir qual seria a mais indicada para o meu projeto?

Comment: Eu tinha postado um comentário aqui, não me lembro de ter problemas no comentário, mas ok como disse anteriormente, vai variar muito do ambiente, até que a resposta do @Gabe vai direto ao problema *"o 3 é o futuro"* e logo o desenvolvimento do 2 irá parar, mas não é porque irá parar o desenvolvimento que irá parar com correções de segurança e que servidores e ou sistemas operacionais irão migrar para o 3 por causa da compatibilidade de apps. O 3 é diferente do 2, mas o importante é aprender lógica de programação, depois vai ser fácil ir do 2 para o 3, a tipagem do Python é relativamente fácil.

Comment: Como a pergunta foi reformulada, eu considerei seu comentário anterior obsoleto e removi. Esse agora está mais completo, poderia até ser o embrião de uma resposta...

Comment: @bfavaretto ótima sugestão, só não vou faze-lo ainda porque estou um pouco atarefado, gosto de tentar fornecer algo com maior qualidade. Obrigado!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Python 3 é o futuro e o presente do Python**. As duas versões são mantidas paralelamente, por enquanto, porque a versão 3 não foi projetada para ser retrocompatível com o código existente em Python 2. Assim, quiseram tomar o cuidado de preservar o ecossistema (bibliotecas, frameworks, etc) enquanto todos se adaptavam à nova versão:

> Acredito que mais uma ou duas versões 2.x serão lançadas, mesmo depois do lançamento da versão 3.0, provavelmente quando já estivermos no 3.1 ou 3.2. Isso também vai depender da demanda pela continuidade do suporte ao 2.x, a aceitação e estabilidade do 3.0 e da disposição da comunidade.
>   <sub>*Guido van Rossum - [PEP 3000](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3000/)*</sub>

O plano não ocorreu exatamente como previsto, demorou bastante tempo e deu bastante o que falar, mas hoje o ecossistema em torno do Python 3 está completamente maduro e o Python 2 caminha para o fim da sua vida:

> Não há lançamento do Python 2.8. A versão 2.8 nunca será lançada. É um ex-lançamento. O Python 2.7 é o fim da linha de desenvolvimento do Python 2.
>   <sub>*Barry Warsaw - [PEP 0404](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0404/)* [anunciando a extinção dos planos de lançamento do Python 2.8]</sub>

Demorou mais que o previsto, mas hoje já não faz sentido começar um novo projeto em Python 2.

A maior parte das bibliotecas mais usadas em python já dão suporte a Python 3, e as poucas que ainda não dão foram substituidas por outras, já criadas em Python 3. Você pode acompanhar o progresso da adaptação ao Python 3 em sites como o [Python 3 Readiness](http://py3readiness.org) que lista os 360 pacotes mais populares do [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi). Pode também usar o [Can I Use Python 3](https://caniusepython3.com) para colocar as dependências do seu projeto e ver se os pacotes que você usa dão suporte a Py3.

Se você está começando com Python agora, **não há motivo para usar Python 2**.
Tudo que você precisa já está disponível em Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

**Comece seus estudos pelo Python 3**. Ele traz várias melhorias e novas funcionalidades, além de ser mais compatível com padrões atuais de programação.

## Explicação Longa

[image: Buscas no Google demonstram a queda de popularidade da versão 2.7 do Python]
Buscas no Google entre a versão 3 (vermelha) e a versão 2.7 (azul) do Python.

A versão 2.7 do Python foi lançada em 3 de julho de 2010. Na época, a versão 2.7 do Python trouxe muitas melhorias em relação às versões anteriores, incluindo:

- **Adição de novos módulos**, como o "argparse" para análise de argumentos de linha de comando
- **Melhorias no desempenho** e na eficiência de memória
- Suporte a novas funções e recursos, incluindo a inclusão de itertools.combinations e itertools.permutations
- **Adição de funcionalidades** ao módulo "unittest"
- **Adição de recursos** para tornar a linguagem mais fácil de usar e mais parecida com as linguagens de programação de alto nível
- **Correção de bugs** e melhorias na compatibilidade com outras plataformas.

Essas características fizeram do Python 2.7 um sucesso ao ponto que até hoje existem empresas utilizando.

Embora a versão mais recente do Python seja a 3.11, muitas empresas ainda dependem de sistemas antigos que foram escritos na versão 2.7, e mudar para uma versão mais recente pode ser **complicado ou inviável devido às mudanças significativas na sintaxe e nos recursos entre as versões**.

Além disso, algumas bibliotecas importantes ainda não foram atualizadas para a versão 3, o que significa que algumas empresas não podem mudar ainda. Por esses motivos, ainda é comum ver o Python 2.7 sendo usado em algumas empresas.

### Fim da Jornada

O Python 2.7 foi oficialmente declarado como "deprecated" (obsoleto) em 1 de janeiro de 2020. A partir desta data, **a equipe de desenvolvimento do Python não fornece mais suporte técnico para a versão 2.7**, incluindo correções de bugs e segurança.

Embora a versão 2.7 ainda possa ser usada, a equipe recomenda fortemente que as pessoas migrem para a versão mais recente do Python (3.x) para obter acesso a recursos mais recentes e melhor suporte.

**Na prática o que significa dizer que o Python 2.7 não terá mais suporte?**

Significa que a partir de uma data específica, o desenvolvimento de novos recursos e correções de bugs para a versão 2.7 do Python serão descontinuados, e não haverá mais suporte oficial para correções de segurança. Isso significa que usuários do Python 2.7 eventualmente precisarão migrar para versões mais recentes do Python para continuar recebendo atualizações e suporte.

### Python 3

A adoção do Python 3 tem crescido significativamente nos últimos anos. De acordo com as estatísticas disponíveis, a maioria dos desenvolvedores de software já estão usando a versão 3 do Python.

No entanto, a versão 2 ainda é amplamente utilizada em algumas aplicações específicas e empresas, então a migração para o Python 3 ainda não está completamente concluída. Com o fim do suporte oficial da versão 2.7, a tendência é que a adoção do Python 3 continue a aumentar no futuro.

#### Python 2.7 vs 3

Existem várias diferenças entre Python 2.7 e Python 3, mas algumas das principais são:

**[image: Fonte: https://codigo35.com/2023/02/06/como-programar-em-python]
Fonte: https://codigo35.com/2023/02/06/como-programar-em-python**

### Mercado de Trabalho

O mercado tem procura por desenvolvedores Python 3. Como a versão 3 do Python é a versão mais recente e tem recursos melhorados em comparação com a versão 2, muitas empresas e projetos estão procurando por desenvolvedores com conhecimento na versão 3.

Além disso, como a versão 2 não terá mais suporte oficial, muitas empresas estão buscando atualizar seus sistemas para a versão 3 para garantir a segurança e a manutenibilidade a longo prazo. Portanto, ter conhecimento em Python 3 é uma vantagem importante para os desenvolvedores na atualidade.

Fazendo uma rapida busca no Linkedin de oportunidades para Programadores Python, você notará que a esmagadora maioria das vagas Python são para a versão 3 da linguagem: [Python 3](https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?currentJobId=3417852233&keywords=%22Python%203%22&refresh=true) vs [Python 2.7](https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?currentJobId=3435674216&geoId=106057199&keywords=%22Python%202.7%22&location=Brazil&refresh=true)

Comment: Atualizado! Obrigado por mencionar o erro, Augusto!